# Name of application in the facebook login prompt

Tags: ios, facebook

I want to change my application name that is displayed on the facebook login prompt

[image: Description: UI Prompt. Text: eldorado wants to use facebook.com to Sign In. This allows the app and website to share information about you. Buttons: Cancel, Continue]

How can I do this?

Comment: in the facebook developer console I think

Comment: There is no way to change it in the developers' console.

Comment: then either you didn't find it, or there is no way to change it at all.

Answer (score 1):

To change the name you should go to project/build settings in Xcode. change Product name. it picks the name from project/build settings